# SQLite - Group by where more than x

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got three tables which relate to support ticket data for a software development firm, the tables are arranged like so:

```
Tickets
[PK] 
ID     Ticket_Type  Type                Created         Resolved
s-100  s            Bug                 1434725860524   1463075456304
d-29   d            Deployment          1434724333500   1463665757667
p-50   p            Upgrade             1434722686876   1466575675677
s-25   s            Training Issue      1434723799989   1465675675677

P-ticket_links
[PK]
Pticket    Link
p-50       s-100
p-50       s-102
p-50       d-29

D-ticket_servers
[PK]
ID     Server
d-29   Live Server
d-30   Test Server
d-31   Live Server
```

The primary key columns in the bottom two tables are also foreign keys which reference the `ID` column of the `Tickets` table.

For each `p` ticket of `Type` 'Upgrade', I need to find out the number of linked `s` tickets which were created *after* the resolved date of the linked `d` ticket, which itself is of `Type` 'Deployment' and which was carried out against the Live Server.

I've written a query to get the total number of `s` tickets linked to each Upgrade `p` ticket using a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT *,count(ts.id)
from [P-ticket_links] ptls
inner join [Tickets] ts on ts.ID=ptls.Link
inner join [Tickets] ts2 on ts2.ID=ptls.Pticket
where ts.Ticket_Type='s'
and ts2.Type='Upgrade'
group by ptls.Pticket
```

I can also find the resolved date of the Live Server Deployment `d` ticket for each `p` ticket using a similar query. However, what I'm having trouble doing is joining those two results together in order to exclude `s` tickets which were created before the resolved date of the Live Server Deployment `d` ticket.

I've tried creating another alias of the `Tickets` table, filtering it to contain the relevant d-tickets and then putting in a clause like `WHERE tickets1.created > tickets3.resolved`, but that  didn't give me the right results.

I think what I need to do is essentially return a table in which every every row contains one `s` ticket linked to the corresponding `p` ticket as well as the resolved date for the `d` ticket linked to that `p` ticket. I could change my database structure to include the information in the first instance, but I don't want to denormalise my database any more and I feel like I should be able to do this with SQL.

Can anyone point me to how I could achieve this?

Comment: `select *` and only one field in your `group by`? You need a group by on all non-aggregate fields in your select clause (except if your using mySql, I think. But that's another story)

Comment: Your id system will drive you nuts. Just build the PK on (ID,Ticket_Type) and get rid of all those prefixes.

Comment: @Strawberry - Why will that drive me nuts? Those IDs aren't mine - they come from the system from which I've scraped the data. They are natural primary keys. Surely appropriate, therefore?

Comment: @oerkelens - this arrangement seems to work - see my answer below. Why exactly might I need to group on all non-aggregate fields?

Comment: @Charon That's simply SQL standard. When you do not specify which fields you want to group by, you may get unexpected results because of undefined behaviour. Some flavours of SQL (most notably MySql) accept it, but that doesn't make it good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. This is how to return the results that I want:

```
select *,count(*) from [p-ticket_links] ptls

inner join 

(SELECT
ts2.id as 'p-id', 
ts.resolved as 'd-resolved'
FROM [tickets] ts 
inner join [p-ticket_links] ptl on [ptl].link=ts.id
inner join [d-ticket_servers] dts on dts.id=ts.id
inner join [tickets] ts2 on ptl.pticket=ts2.id
inner join [p-ticket_versions] ptvs on ptvs.id=ts2.id

where [ts].type='Deployment'
and dts.server='Live Server'
and ts.summary like '%upgrade%'
and ts2.project_type='Upgrade'
and ts.state <> 'Duplicate') dres on dres.[p-id]=ptls.pticket

inner join [tickets] ts on ts.id=ptls.link
inner join [tickets] ts2 on ts2.id=ptls.pticket

where ts.ticket_type='S'
and ts2.project_type='Upgrade'
and ts.created > dres.[d-resolved]

group by ptls.pticket
```